# Who to make split for comma, but not for quoted commas in Java

Tags: java, regex, split

I need make split for commas on a String.
But I need ignore commas inside the text fields

**Input example**:

```
'Field1','Field2','Field3, this field, has, multiples commas','Field4'
```

**Output that I want:**

```
'Field1'
'Field2'
'Field3, this field, has, multiples commas'
'Field4'
```

**Output that I got:**

```
'Field1'
'Field2'
'Field3
 this field,
 has,
 multiples commas'
'Field4'
```

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
,(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

You can split on this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cD5jK1/10

Comment: This regex works on demo... But when i put it on split() method i got java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 8.

Comment: Now its do split inside of the field3, and not between field3 and field4 =(

Comment: @Roqueirow see demo.it is working as expected